# Segmentation fault while importing sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I try to import scikit-learn in python, I get a segmentation fault

```
>>>import sklearn as sk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this?
I am running python 2.7.11 on Fedora.
I installed sklearn using pip
I tried the same using Anaconda on a virtual environment, with the same results.

The same problem doesn't occur on Ubuntu 16, which I ended up installing and using for my purposes.

Comment: In order to even begin helping we'll need more information – how did you install sklearn, what os are you using, are you using a virtualenv, etc?

Comment: updated. Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use pip? 
Take a look at the anaconda method

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fully delete it from pip.

Then try to do the following:

Create a virtual environment with virtualenv for python 2.7 and install sklearn with pip again. Is the error still occuring now?

Comment: Yes. I ended up just doing it on Ubuntu

Comment: How to fully delete from pip? I'm facing the same problem.